# Is there a way to NOT host the web-app on localhost during development?

Tags: reactjs, rust, vite, tauri

## Context

Im using ReactJS with Vite as the frontend and [this](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/setup/integrate) document for reference to setup a basic Tauri App.

For running the App whenever I run

```
npm run tauri dev
```

Vite start hosts the same app locally on localhost along with Tauri's build.

## Expectation

I am expecting a way to STOP Vite from creating just the Tauri build should run.

I understand that when creating a Release build for the app this issue will not be there but is there any way to avoid this during development

Comment: The tauri build is nothing more then a wrapper around a webpage. The alternative would be to make a production build and test that. Then re-build it after every code change. Seems like a really bad idea. Do you have any actual reason to want this?

Comment: No reason in particular, just got started with rust and tauri and within a few blogs/videos/tutorials that I followed nobody mentioned this behaivor so I felt I must be missing out on something. But I see your point here, can really cant really convene with the re-build idea that you shared :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just running the rust part via:

```bash
cd src-tauri
cargo run
```

And you will see cargo compile and run the dev version:

```
   Compiling tauri-app v0.0.0 (~/tauri-app/src-tauri)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.54s
     Running `target/debug/tauri-app`
```

And if you need to run the vite or any other build system that will listen on 1420 port on dev, then you can run it separately via:

```bash
npm run dev
```

If you want to specify different ip or port, you can edit `vite.config.ts` with something like this:

```js
...
server: {
    host: external ? await internalIpV4() : "0.0.0.0",
    port: 1420,
    hmr: mobile
      ? {
          protocol: "ws",
          host: await internalIpV4(),
          port: 1421,
        }
      : undefined,
    strictPort: true,
  },
...
```

Comment: Running just ```npm run tauri``` by itself doesnt work, the command needs an option.

Comment: @AnmolMoudgil ok, updated the answer, use: ```cd src-tauri & cargo run```

Comment: Perfect this works, needed a tiny update in ```tauri.conf.json```, earlier my devpath there was pointing to ```localhost:5173``` and since ```cargo run``` didnt start any server, tauri was failing to load resources. but pointing it to ```../dist``` directory worked !!! thanks :)

Comment: but now since devpath is set to ```../dist``` directory I cant use HMR anymore and have to build the app every time I make some changes. Something like what @super mentioned.

Comment: great, have you tried running the server first, and keep the conf pointing to the localhost?

if my answer helped address your initial question, feel free to mark it as the answer.